# sed and variable substitution

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have the following script which replaces the private key in a properties file.

```
#!/bin/bash

PUBLIC_KEY="1111\n2222\n3333"
PRIVATE_KEY="aaaa\nbbbb\ncccc"

sed -i "s|__PUBLIC_KEY__|${PUBLIC_KEY}|g" config.properties
sed -i "s|__PRIVATE_KEY__|${PRIVATE_KEY}|g" config.properties
```

Before replacement config.properties looks like this:

```
publicKey="__PUBLIC_KEY__"
privateKey="__PRIVATE_KEY__"
```

After replacement the file looks like this:

```
    publicKey="1111
2222
3333"
    privateKey="aaaa
bbbb
cccc"
```

The \n characters seem to be gone after substitution and is breaking my code.

Can someone suggest what is the ideal solution or some workaround.

Comment: If you need a literal backslash + `n` as the replacement, double the backslash

Comment: Hi Wiktor, can you please give an example. Also If there is another solution possible, I would like to not process 
 or escape the value of the variable.

Comment: https://ideone.com/a5mEhh?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are on BASH, you could use pattern substitution:

```
PUBLIC_KEY="1111\n2222\n3333"
PRIVATE_KEY="aaaa\nbbbb\ncccc"

sed -i "s|__PUBLIC_KEY__|${PUBLIC_KEY//\n/\\n}|g" config.properties
sed -i "s|__PRIVATE_KEY__|${PRIVATE_KEY//\n/\\n}|g" config.properties
```

It keeps `PUBLIC_KEY` and `PRIVATE_KEY` unaltered.

Answer (score -1):

`PUBLIC_KEY=$(echo $PUBLIC_KEY | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')

PRIVATE_KEY=$(echo $PRIVATE_KEY | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')`

Add these lines before sed command this worked for me

these lines change single slash () with double (\),

Comment: "this worked for me". Are you sure? Not for me.

Comment: worked in bash version = 4.3.48